# Change text color of Substance LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I'm trying to change the text color of the Substance Look and Feel (in fact I'm using the SubstanceGraphiteGlassLookAndFeel  .
I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately you have to mess with the color schemes.

Since you are using the Graphite Glass skin, messing with the color schemes is considerably easier since they values are not set in Java code.  If you copy he file `/org/pushingpixels/substance/api/skin/graphite.colorschemes` into your classpath, you can go into the various scheme definitions and change the colorForeground entries to be whatever you want.  Possibly black (`#FFFFFF`) or the various greys (`#cccccc`, `#999999`, `#666666`, `#333333`).  But since they are hex colors you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks shemnon. It's exactly what I expected!

Answer (score 1):

1. change all `Keys` in `UIManager` by killing all things that to create this great theme

   - change value for all `Keys` in `UIManager` for all `JComponents` or concrete `JComponent`
   - change value for all value in `Highlighter`(s) for all `JComponents` or concrete `JComponent`
   - I'm not sure if this theme to use or not the `Trident` too, have to check on former `Kirill's forum`
2. or simpler to change for concrete `JComponents` instance, have to repeated for all `JComponents`
3. disclaimer

   > never to change `Colors` or `Fonts` for `Custom Look and Feels`, have to check if `is or isn't` there direct way implemented by `author of L&F`, never to tried that for all `JComponents` and this theme isn't my favorite, then point second is safer by eliminate side effect implemented in `Custom L&F`, but in this case you probably to loose implemented `Highlighter`(s)

Comment: Playing with the UIManager in Substance won't work.  Krill subverted that path for the most part, at least when it comes to the substance UI delegates.

Comment: @shemnon I used that for Substance where Painter or HightLighter isn't used, I doubt to change the value into colorschemes for JButtons Components only, my view, your is described ...